# UI5 dialog increases its size when the hidden input field is shown

Tags: sapui5

I have a `sap.m.Dialog` form:

[image: sap.m.Dialog]

When I click on «Forgot password?», I show a hidden `sap.m.Input` field:

[image: sap.m.Input]

The problem is that the extended form is now much bigger then the original one.

I've tried to figure out why but can't find a source of the issue.

A click on the «Forgot password?» calls `onResetPasswordForm`:

```js
onResetPasswordForm() {

    // hide the reset password form
    if (oView.byId("resetPasswordUsername").getVisible()) {

        oView.byId("username").focus();

        oView.byId("resetPasswordUsername").setVisible(false);
        oView.byId("btnResetPassword").setVisible(false);

        oView.byId("resetPasswordUsername").setValue("");

    // show the reset password form
    } else {

        oView.byId("resetPasswordUsername").focus();

        oView.byId("resetPasswordUsername").setValue("");

        oView.byId("resetPasswordUsername").setVisible(true);
        oView.byId("btnResetPassword").setVisible(true);

    }

}
```

XML-template:

```xml
<core:FragmentDefinition
    xmlns:core = "sap.ui.core"
    xmlns = "sap.m">

    <Dialog
        id = "authDialog"
        contentWidth = "300px"
        title = "{i18n>AUTH_DIALOG_DIALOG_TITLE}"
        type = "Message"
        escapeHandler = ".escapeHandler">

        <Label
            labelFor = "username"
            text = "{i18n>AUTH_DIALOG_LAB_USERNAME}" />

        <Input
            id = "username"
            liveChange = ".onLiveChange"
            placeholder = "{i18n>AUTH_DIALOG_PH_USERNAME}"
            type = "Text" />

        <Label
            labelFor = "password"
            text = "{i18n>AUTH_DIALOG_LAB_PASSWORD}" />

        <Input
            id = "password"
            liveChange = ".onLiveChange"
            placeholder = "{i18n>AUTH_DIALOG_PH_PASSWORD}"
            type = "Password" />

        <Link
            id = "showHideResetPasswordForm"
            text = "{i18n>AUTH_DIALOG_PASSWORD_FORGOT}"
            class = "authFormHelperText"
            press = ".onResetPasswordForm" />

        <Input
            id = "resetPasswordUsername"
            visible = "false"
            liveChange = ".onLiveChange"
            placeholder = "{i18n>AUTH_DIALOG_PH_USERNAME}"
            type = "Text" />

        <beginButton>
            <Button
                id = "btnResetPassword"
                enabled = "false"
                visible = "false"
                press = ".onResetPassword"
                text = "{i18n>AUTH_DIALOG_BTN_RESET_PASSWORD}"
                type = "Emphasized" />
        </beginButton>

        <endButton>
            <Button
                id = "btnLogin"
                enabled = "false"
                press = ".onPressLogin"
                text = "{i18n>AUTH_DIALOG_BTN_SUBMIT}"
                type = "Emphasized" />
        </endButton>

    </Dialog>

</core:FragmentDefinition>
```

How can I show a hidden `sap.m.Input` without changing the initial `sap.m.Dialog` sizes?

Comment: Can you show us the XML of the Dialog content? Is it a Simple form?

Comment: @Cmdd, I've added. It's a `FragmentDefinition`.

Comment: It looks perfectly fine to me. I don't know if the absence of a label for the hidden input plays a role here...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can control the content size with the properties [`contentWidth`](https://github.com/SAP/openui5/blob/d6e82ee06db46b285742346e7dd0e7b90194b868/src/sap.m/src/sap/m/Dialog.js#L235-L246) and [`contentHeight`](https://github.com/SAP/openui5/blob/d6e82ee06db46b285742346e7dd0e7b90194b868/src/sap.m/src/sap/m/Dialog.js#L235-L246).

---

Update after the [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67976595/#comment120155848_67977097):

> but more interesting is the reason *why* does the showing of extra [content] leads to change the dialogue window size?

That's probably the native behavior of Blink (Chromium's layout engine). If an additional HTMLElement needs to be rendered and the Dialog's `<div>` element does **not** specify the `width` explicitly ([`getContentWidth()` returning an empty value](https://github.com/SAP/openui5/blob/419de749f4ee93ba2a69f09c8083d16387e60621/src/sap.m/src/sap/m/DialogRenderer.js#L59)), the sizes of the `<div>` grow automatically along with the content.

According to [this comment](https://github.com/SAP/openui5/blob/58ae48cd6371ab43be1260961053155bfc3b34fd/src/sap.m/src/sap/m/Dialog.js#L1118), other browsers behave differently. So the Dialog tries to "fix" it in that case.

Comment: Thanks. Of course I can hardcoded the dialogue size but more interesting is the reason _why_ does the showing of extra input field leads to change the dialogue window size? I've tried to reduce the length of `placeholder` text but it doesn't help.

Comment: Thanks! Should I consider opening a ticket at the UI5's Git?

Comment: @MikeB. No, because it's the [intended behavior](https://github.com/SAP/openui5/blob/6dcf8c8ee477090b064f4b9e02874e4e3ccb65fe/src/sap.m/src/sap/m/Dialog.js#L160) _("If there is no specific sizing, the Dialog will try to adjust its size to its content.")_. The maintainers would recommend the same thing that you should specify the `contentWidth`.

Answer (score 0):

Try to set the height of Dialog with vh. Hope that will work.